# Modeling overlapping HTML spans w/ different CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, html

I'm looking for a good way to model something keeping track of different overlapping CSS groups, similar to the following:

1. This is just a test sentence for an example.
2. (This is) just a (test sentence) for an example.
3. (This is just) a test (sentence for an example.)

Depending on what radio buttons are selected, I'd like to to enable different CSS styles for each of the groups in parenthesis. So for #2 for example, (This is) will always have a different default style, and will highlight red when moused over, but only when option 2 is selected. There will be a lot of different options, so I'd like to avoid having multiple copies of the source text if necessary.

The problem is that you can't have spans overlap. The only way I could thing of doing this is giving each word multiple css classes, like:

group2_word1,group3_word1, etc..., and then do a lot of javascript coding to simulate the behavior I want. This sounds like a terrible idea to me.

Is there a better way?

Comment: you will end up writing JS anyways...

Answer (score 0):

I remember a javascript library that was able to do word/letter based inline text styling but I do not remember the name. All I could find out by now is a lib called [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/). Maybe you want to give it a try. I will try to find the other lib too and report back if I find it.

Take a look at the [CSSClassApplierModule](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) that could do just what you are looking for.